# How do I escape the characters `<` and `>` in search and replace strings passed to sed?

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I want to replace `<title>` with `<title>FRED`, using `sed`.   I have tried the below to no avail.

```
19:46: scratch $ sed -i '/<title>/<title>FRED/' index.html
sed: -e expression #1, char 10: unknown command: `<'
======================================================================================================================
19:47: scratch $ sed -i '/\<title>/<title>FRED/' index.html
sed: -e expression #1, char 11: unknown command: `<'
======================================================================================================================
19:48: scratch $ sed -i "/\<title>/<title>FRED/" index.html
sed: -e expression #1, char 11: unknown command: `<'
```

How then, do I escape the characters `<` and `>` correctly?

Or is it something else I'm not getting?

Comment: [Don't Parse XML/HTML With Regex.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3776858) I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, xmllint ...).

Comment: What's wrong with `sed`?   I just want, in a script, to add some text to a file. And the text I'm searching for contains `<` and `>`.   Let's forget it's HTML please!  What should I use if not `sed`?

Comment: `sed` is fine for editing *unstructured* text. Regular expressions aren't powerful enough to correctly parse HTML, at least not without knowing very specifically how that HTML is formatted.

Comment: I don't need to "parse HTML".   Let's say I just need to find text in a string that has `<` in it!   I thought I could escape special characters with a `\\`backslash.

Comment: Some variation using back reference `sed -ri 's/(<title>)/\1FRED/' file` or `sed -i 's/\(<title>\)/\1FRED/' file`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't specified a command. You presumably wanted the substitution command

```
sed -i 's/<title>/<title>FRED/' index.html
```

Without the `s`, `sed` thinks that `/<title>/` is an address for the command `<` (which doesn't exist in `sed`).